# Does iOS 17 interactive widget views support rendering a pdf document?

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipad, widget, ios17

I am new to developing widgets for iPads, and I understand that iOS 17 lets developers create interactive widgets for iPads that support buttons and toggles.

I have a requirement to display a PDF in a widget using SwiftUI. Does the widget view support rendering PDF's using PDFKit or any other alternative?